# Create a button having description using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im looking for something like this

[image]

There is a small description ($10 USD ) given for the button. Can anyone help me how to create one?

I have an anchor button like this.Can any one help me create such a description using css?

```
<a style="float:right" class="iframe button pink" href="">Pay Now</a>
```

this is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wLmbw/

Comment: actually that's only 1 image, that looks like 2, and the 'description' is the `alt` tag from html 5

Comment: Do u want a basic tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/wLmbw/3/ or something more fancy?

Comment: are you after tooltips? check http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

Comment: @jcho360 Its not like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's static content you could add a small container via a :before element.

```
.button.pink{
    position: relative;
}

.button.pink:before{
    position: absolute;
    left: -90%;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 10px;
    content: "$10";
    background: #6FCC49;
    border: 1px solid #679500;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #679500;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etasf/2/

[image]

This could probably be cleaned up - this was just my quick run at it.

Comment: Pseudo elements are a nice way to get extra content without extra HTML markup, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

add another html element like the picture on the left,
position it using css
and use javacsript to populate the right value

Answer (score 0):

You might want something along these lines:

HTML:

```
<a style="float:right" class="iframe button pink" href="">
<span class="label">10 USD</span>Pay Now</a>
```

CSS

```
.pink{
    position:relative;
}
.label
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    right:105%;
    bottom: -1px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color:pink;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLmbw/)

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you know how to style an `div`, or `span`, element. Place it right next to the button and set it to `css.display:none`. And when the user hovers over the button, then set it to `css.display:block` using javascript...